# Set of all holomorphic function on Riemann surface is a C- Algebra

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let $ W \subset X$ is an open subset of a Riemann surface $X$ , we will denote the set of holomorphic functions on $W$ by $O_{X}(W)=\{ f : W \rightarrow \mathbb{C }| f  $ is holomorphic $\}$. How to show that $O_{X}(W)$ is a $ \mathbb{C}-$ algebra.
My aim is to show there exists a ring homomorphism  $h :\mathbb{C}\rightarrow O_{X}(W)$.

Basically for each $z\in C $ we have to get a holomorphic map.
How can I get that map ?

Comment: Hint: Constant functions are holomorphic.

Comment: Okay. You are saying for each $z\in \mathbb{C}$ we should take the map f(w)=z .

Comment: Yeah I think it will work.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. You can also get that it should be like this by considering the natural $\mathbb{C}$-algebra structur $$\mathbb{C}\times O_X(W)\rightarrow O_X(W), (a, z\mapsto f(z)) \mapsto (z\mapsto af(z)).$$

Comment: Okay I understood. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you write an answer, spelling out the details. It might be helpful for other people in the future (and allows you to gain some reputation).